# jQuery - onClick animate ScrollLeft - Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple web page with 1 main container and 4 fullscreen divs and I am trying to make them scroll horizontally. Example I click div 1 then viewport moves to div 2, etc. I already made this work vertically in another instance using the scrollTop method.

I can scroll the page to other divs manually without a problem, but it does not work on click. There is a fiddle attached with a close example, you will have to scroll with the arrow keys (I have yet to fix the mouse wheel scroll issue).

https://jsfiddle.net/58j2dg3a/36/

This is the js code I am using to animate Scroll Left.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#one").click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollLeft: $("#two").offset().left
    }, 1000);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scrollLeft` is being set on the html and body elements, but it should be set on `.container`.

As a suggestion, you might want to look into using [CSS Scroll Snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type), which lets you do this sort of thing without JavaScript.

Comment: Your solution did work, but now when I click on the second div, nothing happens, and when I click on the third div it takes me back to the second one. The first and forth div work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

As Luke Channings suggested, I was not using the correct element to scroll. I just finished experimenting and I got good results. Instead of telling scrollLeft to move BY X amount of px, I now tell it WHERE to move. I needed this to be responsive, so each time I trigger the function I would get the viewport width and multiply it by x, depending which div I want to show.

Fiddle is the updated and final version.

https://jsfiddle.net/b5g7dhyv/

Code for jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#one').on('click', function(){
    let viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#main-wrapper').animate({scrollLeft : viewportWidth}, 1000);
  })
  $('#two').on('click', function(){
    let viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#main-wrapper').animate({scrollLeft : viewportWidth*2}, 1000);
  })
  $('#three').on('click', function(){
    let viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#main-wrapper').animate({scrollLeft : viewportWidth*3}, 1000);
  })
  $('#four').on('click', function(){

    $('#main-wrapper').animate({scrollLeft : 0}, 1000);
  })

});
```